# Is loc or xs faster in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Is df.loc or df.xs faster in very large pandas dataframes?
Also, what about in the case of a multiIndex?

```
df.loc[index1].loc[index2]
```

vs.

```
df.xs([index1,index2],level=[0,1])
```

Or is it just better if I convert everything into a Python dictionary? (I have about 4-5 nested indexes for my datasets) - apparently this has been the fastest so far me, but it just didn't seem right..

Comment: I'm not surprised that a Python dictionary is faster, but I doubt it's nearly as scalable and it's definitely not as flexible.

Comment: I timed it.loc seems to be faster for large, xs for small _df_s. I was wondering about the architecture behind this and if there are any specific rules.

Comment: @csaladenes: I think [this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6683) discussion could help you out here