# for a Multi-Indexed DataFrame which has better performance df.loc vs df.xs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is an example Multi-Indexed DataFrame:

```py
days = ['Day 1', 'Day 1', 'Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 2', 'Day 2']
meals = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
hier_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(days, meals)))
arr_5 = np.random.randint(500, 700, size=(6, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr_5, hier_index, ['M', 'F'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```py
           M    F
Day 1 1  519  582
      2  686  613
      3  535  537
Day 2 1  516  602
      2  607  522
      3  662  637
```

using [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```py
df.loc['Day 1']
```

using [xs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```py
df.xs('Day 1')
```

what has better performance?

---

I know this has been asked before but for 7 years it has got no answer [Other Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073217/is-loc-or-xs-faster-in-pandas)

Comment: you can make a large dataset, time it, and come back with a result (if no one else has done it yet)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the benchmarking result for some concrete data for comparison:

```
%%timeit
df.loc['Day 1']

152 µs ± 4.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
df.xs('Day 1')

142 µs ± 3.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`.loc` vs `.xs` is **152 µs**  vs **142 µs**
**`.xs` is around 7% faster** for a dataset of 6 rows

---

**Let's compare in a data size 10000x of the original size:**

```
df2 = pd.concat([df] * 10000)
```

```
%%timeit
df2.loc['Day 1']

1.43 ms ± 55.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
df2.xs('Day 1')

1.37 ms ± 27.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

`.loc` vs `.xs` is **1.43 ms**  vs **1.37 ms**
**`.xs` is around 4.3% faster**  for a dataset of 60,000 rows

### Conclusion

Based on a very simple benchmarking result, the rough conclusion is that **their performance magnitude is roughly the same**.  With **`.xs` just marginally faster** (a few % difference).

Comment: Absolutely agree, also it depends of number of unique keys in MultiIndex, `df2 = pd.concat([df] * 10000)` create few big groups, not sure if good for test.